# How to bring an awesome wm client back from being minimized with the keyboard?

Tags: awesome

You can switch between clients with <kbd>Mod</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> and <kbd>Mod</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>.

You can minimize clients with <kbd>Mod</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>.

But once you've minimized a client; how do you switch to it so you can display it normally again with some other keyboard combination?

When I use <kbd>Mod</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> and <kbd>Mod</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> all my minimized clients get skipped over.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default keyboard shortcut is <kbd>Mod</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>. ([Source](https://github.com/awesomeWM/awesome/blob/c5e830cd6031643eb8046c9f05145ad7a54f58ce/awesomerc.lua#L321))

The API function being used is [`awful.client.restore()`](https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/classes/client.html#awful.client.restore).